# Different output in IDE and Console || Javscript

Tags: javascript, async-await, console, settimeout

For the following code :

```
const thenable = {
  then: function(callback) {
    setTimeout(() => callback(2), 100);
  }
};

const value = await thenable;
console.log(value);// 2 in console and error in JSFIDDLE
```

output while executing the code snippet in chrome console is 2 but while executing the same in JSFiddle there is an error ie syntaxError; which it really should be as await keyword must be used inside an async function.

Comment: jsfiddle wraps all the code in a `window.onload` function and it's not declared `async`.

Comment: what about the console? why logging in 2 there?

Comment: The console allows you to call async functions directly.